# How do I setup URL Rewrite's with SharePoint 2010 correctly?

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, team-foundation-server

My current setup looks like this:

```
Internet -> IIS Web Server (IIS1)
              -> domain1.com
                    -> stuff.domain1.com
                    -> morestuff.domain1.com
              -> domain2.com
              -> domain3.com
         -> Team Foundation/SharePoint/SQL Server (TFS)
```

IIS1 is configured with multiple sites using host headers mapped to local directories.

TFS is configured with a very standard SQL/SharePoint/TFS setup, as close to default as I could get.  I have done no configuration with host headers, DNS, or alternate access mappings on this server in SharePoint or in the Application Tier of TFS.  "Stock install" comes to mind.

All traffic over port 80 is routed to IIS1.

What is the proper way to setup external access to the TFS SharePoint site, is it to create a URL Rewrite for IIS1's subdomain.domain1.com to point to the TFS server, and if so - do I need both an incoming and outgoing rule?

Will I also need to modify host headers on the TFS server?  Do I need to setup some sort of DNS service as well?  Configure alternate access mappings?  I'm a tad lost.

If not, what is the best way to set this up?  Ideally I would like to access the SharePoint services offered by Team Foundation Server at somesubdomain.domain1.com (externally/remotely).

Comment: So... you are port forwarding http requests againts TFS to IIS1?! Why would you do that? How will you access Sharepoint over http?